# PHP 7 update and imagejpg text character broken

Tags: character, imagettftext, imagejpeg

I'm using imagettftext and imagepng or imagejpeg.
The character problem does not occur when I use it in PHP 5.6 version.
But when I upgrade to php 7 this problem starts.
The characters of other country languages ​​appear corrupted. No change in code.
Problem only when i upgrade php 5.6 version to 7.4
I would be very grateful if anyone with an idea could post it.
Thank you. This text : TEST Çiçek Sok. Çiç
[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

```
$item_text = mb_encode_numericentity($item_text,
array (0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8');
```

this worked for me. But why does this happen in 7 while php 5.6 doesn't have this issue?